# Duplicate items in useState

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I want to create a state, saving all 18 pokemon types using PokeAPI (endpoint : `https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/type/${typeId}`).

It's not the first time I fetch data into a useEffect and save it with useState,but with a single data.

This time, I want to push data into my state using loop, prevState and spread operator to fill the array. Maybe due to strict mode and his double render, it push everything twice, with 36 entries.

```
function App() {
  
  const [types, setTypes] = useState([])
  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchType = async (typeId) => {
      try {
        const res = await axios.get(`https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/type/${typeId}`)
        const data = await res.data
        //console.log(data)
        setTypes((prevState) => [...prevState, data.name])
      } catch (error) {
        console.log(error)
      }
    }

    for (let i = 1; i <= 18; i++) {
      fetchType(i)
    }
  }, [])

  return (
    ...
  )
}
```

Output:

```
[
  "normal",
  "fighting",
  "flying",
  "poison",
  "ground",
  "rock",
  "bug",
  "ghost",
  "steel",
  "fire",
  "water",
  "grass",
  "electric",
  "normal",
  "fighting",
  "psychic",
  "flying",
  "poison",
  "ice",
  "ground",
  "dragon",
  "dark",
  "rock",
  "fairy",
  "bug",
  "ghost",
  "steel",
  "fire",
  "water",
  "grass",
  "electric",
  "psychic",
  "ice",
  "dragon",
  "dark",
  "fairy"
]
```

How can I prevent this behaviour without removing strict mode?

Or, is their an completely different way to create this array?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**effect cleanup**

Yes it's a React 18 strict mode thing. It's important your components cleanup after themselves and don't attempt to set state on unmounted components. See the [Fetching Data](https://beta.reactjs.org/learn/you-might-not-need-an-effect#fetching-data) guide from the React docs for more details.

```js
  React.useEffect(() => {
    let mounted = true // ✅ initialize flag
    const fetchType = async (typeId) => {
      try {
        const res = await ...
        if (mounted) { // ✅ only setState on mounted components
          setTypes(...)
        }
      } catch (error) {
        ...
      }
    }

    for (...) {
      fetchType(i)
    }
    return () => {
      mounted = false // ✅ unset flag when component unmounts
    }
  }, [])
```

**demo**

Here's a verifiable example to show it working properly. Note -

- `fetch` is used in place of `axios`
- StackOverflow snippets do not support JSX when used with async/await so `React.createElement` is used. Feel free to use ordinary JSX in your own program.

```js
function App() {
  
  const [types, setTypes] = React.useState([])
  
  React.useEffect(() => {
    let mounted = true
    const fetchType = async (typeId) => {
      try {
        const res = await fetch(`https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/type/${typeId}`)
        const data = await res.json()
        if (mounted) setTypes(s => [...s, data.name])
      } catch (error) {
        console.log(error)
      }
    }
    for (let i = 1; i <= 18; i++) fetchType(i)
    return () => { mounted = false }
  }, [])

  return types.join(", ")
}
const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.querySelector("#app"))
root.render(React.createElement(React.StrictMode, [],
  React.createElement(App, [], [])
))
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@18/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@18/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

**parallel requests**

In the above example, 18 sub-requests are made and the application is re-rendered *each* time a response arrives. This may or may not be what you intended. Another approach is to fire off all sub-requests and render *once* only after all responses have arrived. In this example I also show you how to separate the `fetchType` function from the component to make functions more reusable and keep component logic simplified -

```js
const fetchType = async (typeId) => {
  try {
    const res = await fetch(`https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/type/${typeId}`)
    const data = await res.json()
    return data.name
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error)
  }
}

function App() {
  const [types, setTypes] = React.useState([])
  
  React.useEffect(() => {
    let mounted = true
    const promises = []
    for (let i = 1; i <= 18; i++) promises.push(fetchType(i))
    Promise.all(promises).then(types => {
      if (mounted) setTypes(types) // ✅ single state change
    })
    return () => { mounted = false }
  }, [])

  return types.join(", ")
}
const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.querySelector("#app"))
root.render(React.createElement(React.StrictMode, [],
  React.createElement(App, [], [])
))
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@18/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@18/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can start by initializing the state to an empty array:

```
useEffect(() => {
  setState([]) // <-- initialize the state

  const fetchType = async(typeId) => {
```

This would ensure that the 1st call to `fetchType` would have empty `prevState`.

Another option is to replace the state for the 1st item instead of adding to the existing list:

```
setTypes((prevState) => typeId > 1 ? [...prevState, data.name] : [data.name])
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is indeed due to strict mode. You could build some sort of AbortSignal logic to cancel any requests that are in flight when the second fetch starts.

Here's an example of something I've done in the past in a ts-react project using fetch (I believe axios is almost identical) with a custom hook:

```
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";

export function useFetchOnMount<T>(apiEndpoint: string) {
  const [data, updateData] = useState<T>();

  useEffect(() => {
    const abortController = new AbortController();

    async function fetchData() {
      // pass the abort controller's signal to the fetch API to cancel when notified
      const response = await fetch(apiEndpoint, {
        signal: abortController.signal,
      });
      const data = await response.json();
      updateData(data);
    }

    fetchData();

    return () => {
      // when the component unmounts, send the abort signal to the AbortController
      abortController.abort();
    };
  }, []);

  return { data };
}
```

Additionally, you could create and store a Set rather than an Array. Since a Set only stores unique values, double-adding will not be an issue.

Here's an example of your code with the update (using fetch for my convenience, but it should work pretty similarly):

```
function App() {
  const [types, setTypes] = useState(new Set());
  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchType = async (typeId: number) => {
      try {
        const res = await fetch(`https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/type/${typeId}`);
        const data = await res.json();
        console.log("data", data.name);
        setTypes(
          (prevState) => new Set([...(Array.from(prevState) ?? []), data.name])
        );
      } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
      }
    };

    for (let i = 1; i <= 18; i++) {
      fetchType(i);
    }
  }, []);

  return Array.from(types).map((thing) => <p key={thing}>{thing}</p>);
}
```

Of course, with this approach you have to do a fair bit of conversion between Sets and Arrays. I would prefer the initial approach.

One important thing to note however is that in production mode, strict mode won't force the double render. That being said, this kind of bug can bite you if you aren't thoughtful about this *kind* of edge case in a production environment.

Comment: "when the hook is torn down", maybe change that wording to "when the component unmounts". OP should note aborted fetches reject with an abort error message.